# Import logo from '../../img/logo.png - Can not find module

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am creating a REACT NODEJS Application using Create-React-App

I'm copying from a premade REACT site which imports images like this:

```
import Logo from '../../img/logo.png'
```

but when I do the same in my application, I get the error

```
Can not find module
```

My Folder stucture is:

```
\src\views\home\layout\layout.tsx   \\this is the problem file 
\src\views\img\logo.png                  \\this definitely exists
```

When I use require directly in my JSX it works fine, however I don't want to start off on the wrong foot doing things differently

```
<img src={require("../../img/logo.png")} alt="" /></a>  //Works
```

Comment: Not sure if its a typo, but you say the image lives in `imgs` and yet you import from `img` ?

Comment: this was a typo when writing this question. I will fix it here. (I checked this over and over in my project)

Answer (score 1):

From your folder structure your import statement should look like

`import Logo from '../../../imgs/logo.png'`

Edited and corrected after @zerkms pointed out my folly of counting one extra folder in the path.

Comment: thanks. you are correct, but my question had the typo in it.. i fixed it.. Its not a problem with my folder structure.. it must be missing a module

Comment: Can you please post the exact error you are getting? Also can you please post the code for the img tag where you use the imported image?

Comment: It's considered a "module" because you are importing it. Neither Node nor Webpack has any idea it's an image instead of a script until it actually  tries to load it. The cannot find module error means you do not have any file by the name `logo.png` at the directory location specified. If you have a file by that name, then correct the traversal as noted by @palsrealm so node can find it. If you don't have the file, then go download some png image and place it at that location.